# Invoke function before closing script (Ctrl + C)

Tags: python, scripting

I'm running a local server using `http.server` like this:

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler

class ServerHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_POST(self):
       ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Starting server at "+str(PORT)+"...")
    server = HTTPServer(('', PORT), ServerHandler)
    server.serve_forever()
```

I want to invoke a function before stopping the server using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in the terminal
how do I do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the [solution](https://blenderartists.org/t/invoke-function-before-closing-script-ctrl-c/1409269/3?u=cakelover)

```
import signal

default_handler = None

def handler(num, frame):    
    # Do something that cannot throw here (important)
    print("Hello World")

    return default_handler(num, frame) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    default_handler = signal.getsignal(signal.SIGINT)

    # Assign the new handler
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handler)
```